# Block to saving _sync documents in to couchbase server

Tags: javascript, nosql, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm using couchbase server & couchbase sync gateway as my backend databases. but the problem is once I configured the full setup _sync documents were saved to the central server. I only want to keep my master documents & transaction documents in the couchbase server. is there any approach or solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using latest version of couchbase server (5.1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync Gateway stores '_sync'-prefixed documents to the bucket to manage mobile replication and security information associated with that bucket.  There isn't any way to avoid this at the present time.

Comment: Is there any possibility to order(our documents top in the bucket & _sync documents at last) in couchbase server GUI?

Comment: There's no 'order', but you could exclude them with `_sync is missing`. You could write a N1QL query to do the ordering in the Query Workbench.